# hosting my website on a LAN using tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, iis

I am badly stuck in a doubt that i have tried various ways to get it cleared and coul'nt find a solution and therefore i decided to come back to the good old place where i have never missed out on getting what i want!

I have a simple hello world jsp page that will trigger a java servlet when a button on this page is clicked. I am running it in a tomcat server that i have installed on my laptop. i am using the Eclipse IDE. so when i run my jsp page, it asks if i want to make the server up, and i will say yes and the jsp page comes up in the browser inside eclipse IDE. and i can access the same page through my system's browser (chrome) too using http:/// . (90 is the port that i have configured for this tomcat). but if i hit to the same url pattern as i have told you above on a desktop which is in the same network as my laptop is, nothing comes up and then i thought, i will hit using the IP of my laptop where the server (tomcat) is actually running, still no result.

when i googled a bit, i learnt that IIS server should be running on my windows to achieve what i want. but my doubt is: Is there a difference between IIS server and tomcat server?because tomcat is already running, do i need an IIS server?

**Update - Solution**
i used the private IP of my laptop and then it works!!! i was using teh public IP of my network till now so was unsuccessful!!

Comment: Either you aren't including the port in the url when you try to go to it with the other computer, or you have a firewall on your computer that's running the Tomcat server and its blocking access to that port from everywhere but localhost.  The IIS thing you saw was just if you want to put IIS in front of Tomcat which ain't going to help you here.

Comment: hi, i tried disabling the firewall on the system running tomacat still no luck. tomcat is running on a laptop which is accessing wifi. i tried pinging my lap from the desktop and its reachable. but why am i not able to hit the tomcat server with the IP of my laptop and port properly configured?? please help

Comment: If you're running it through Eclipse it may be that Eclipse is limiting the connection to localhost.  Try actually installing a Tomcat server.

Comment: The reason I suggest that is I know Visual Studio does the same thing with its mini-IIS instance when you are debugging. You couldn't get to it from another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** i used the private IP of my laptop and then it works!!! i was using teh public IP of my network till now so was unsuccessful!!

Answer (score 0):

IIS is a web server while Tomcat is a web container. You can find more information 
[here](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-iis-and-tomcat/)

You dont need IIS to access Tomcat. Tomcat is a standalone web container which can server JSP pages you are trying to access. Simplest thing to do is try to ping your laptop from your desktop. If that doesnt work then your need to check firewall settings as suggested by another user. But if that works, make sure your port and application context name is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: i am able to ping my lap from desktop. but tstill not able to hit the tomcat running on lap

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you are using your public IP address to access the page but nothing happing, it's because the public IP you are seeing is not your laptop's IP. it's your router's IP. Your private IP is your laptop's IP which is assigned by your router. if  you want to access the page using your public IP you have to forward that particular PORT on your router. By doing that you can easily access the page from anywhere not only from your home network but from other networks as well.